# upstart script that runs another script, constantly launching

Tags: linux, upstart

I have an `expect` script named `ex.sh` that interacts with another script 'vpn.sh'. the `vpn.sh` script runs a vpn client so I need Upstart to automatically start it when my server reboots.

Currently I have an upstart job 'myjob.conf' on /etc/init/myjob.conf and what it does is just run `ex.sh`. The problem is that when I see the logs for /var/log/upstart/ex I see that, obviously, ex.sh is being run every minute because the script finish running and starts again, but I don't need this becaus I only need to launch the vpn process once.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: How does `myjob.conf` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `respawn` line from `myjob.conf`.